# Cypress giving error "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established"

Tags: cypress, cypress-session

When i visit baseURL, it will navigate to keycloak login, after entering login details, then it will navigate to production URL.
So, I'm navigating back to baseURL. At that time, it will throw below error in
console. Hence Page is keep on loading.

```
VM245 2.1fc033ba.chunk.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'wss://<proxy URL>' failed: 
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I already setup below configuration in cypress.config.js file

```
e2e: {
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin:true,    
    experimentalSessionSupport:true,
  }
```

If i do same thing in manually, it will work but from cypress tool its not working.
Is there any configuration I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above issue is resolved in new version of Cypress 12.0.2 version.